# Height property CSS

Tags: css, properties, height

What is the difference between height property and max-height property. It is understandable that if we set the max-height to 50px, the height of the element would not exceed 50px. But if  we set only the height to 50px, then also the height would remain 50px. What is the difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically what you said.  A div with a height of 50px will always be 50px tall.

A div with a max-height of 50px can be less than 50px tall, but when the content inside of it pushes it down, the div will become no larger than 50px in height.

Comment: and if it exceeds the max-height of the element, do we have to control it through overflow property or what ?

Comment: Correct.  Once an element reaches its max-height you will need to decided what to do with its overflow just as if it had a set height.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a div block with id my_block.  max_height puts a cap on the maximum allowable height that can be set:

```
#my_block{
    width:20px;
    height:60px;  // You can try to set the height to 60px, but the max-height of 50px won't let you...
    max-height:50px;
    border:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to get an idea of the behavior is to play with the properties height and max-height on JSFiddle (or similar website)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height to 50px is great but it doesn't make adaptable pages.

Instead setting the height to something like 100% means that it will show different heights on different devices with different screen sizes and will be more adaptable.

Setting a max-height setting the max-height to 50px will keep it adaptable but always under 50px.

For example setting the height to 480px would look fine on an iphone however it would look super small on a laptop.  If you set the height to 100% though, it will fill the screen for both :D